# Subtotals in RDLC report

Tags: c#, rdlc

I need to display subtotals in RDLC reports.
My report should display data like this:

```
Book            Student           Borrowed
Book1           John              2
Book1           Mary              3
Book1           Bob               1

                Total:            6 --how to do it?

Book2           Alex              1
Book2           John              7
Book2           Dan               2
                Total:            10 --how to do it?

Grand Total:                      16
```

As you see, I have the data grouped by BookName and StudentName. The last column shows how many times the student borrowed that book last year.
Basically implementing the Grand Total is piece of cake but I can't seem to be able to define a subtotal for each book.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add a group around the details section of the report and group on the book name - you can then add a total in the group footer.  In your example, wouldn't you have separate groups for each of Book2, Book3 and Book4?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I fixed that. Thanks. I will try your suggestion and come back with the result.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a table or matrix, i assume you put that in a list and set the list to group by book-name. That way, what actually happens is that a new table or matrix is generated for each book-name.
If you are using a matrix, to have a subtotal is as simple as right clicking on the matrix detail's first cell and specifying SUBTOTAL in the menu. With a table, go to the footer and specify sum using RunningValue