# How To add Group Footer in VS2010 RDLC Report

Tags: visual-studio-2010, rdlc

How do I add a "group footer" summary row to a group I've created in VS2010 RLDC.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At the bottom of the designer there are Row Groups and Column groups Click the arrow next to Row Groups and click "Add Total".  This adds a footer row...

BUT BE aware...

If you do this on the outermost group, it adds a "Report Footer" showing the totals for ALL the groups, not per group. If you do it on an inner group it adds a "Group Footer" which gives you sub totals for each of the sub groups.

You can also right click on the details row (the one with 3 horizontal lines it the far left box) and go Insert Rows->Below... If you have an inner group and an outer group this adds a "Group Footer" (I have not tested it without the outer group yet).

[image: HowToAddFooterMethod2]

Here is a quick and dirty diagram (sorry about the quality) showing all the parts once you get them set up so it'll make more sense)

[image: AllPartsDiagram]

Comment: Added for posterity because it took me a while to figure it out.

Comment: here is another attempt to answer it if my answer is not helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038075/subtotals-in-rdlc-report