# How to calculate sub total for each page in rdlc report

Tags: c#, asp.net, rdlc

I use this expression for calculate the sub total:

```
=RunningValue(CDbl(Fields!Rate.Value),Sum,"Payslip_DataTable1")
```

and calculate the grand total using this:

```
=Sum(CDbl(Fields!Amount.Value))
```

"Grand Total" is a footer section, but I want to calculate the sub total for each page.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038075/subtotals-in-rdlc-report

Comment: I have unique records...so am not use grouping in my report...then how can i calculate the total amount in each page...

Answer (score 0):

This Query works for me for find out the sub total.

= sum(CDbl(ReportItems!Total_Amount.Value)) (its placed in Page Footer Section)

For Grand Total :

i use rdlc report parameters for finding total amounts in all pages.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this will help you or not, but I just ran into something strange today and might help simplify reporting grand totals, or at page footer, you will have to sample it out.

Within the grid, during a group footer, I would usually have some sub-totals, such as accounting per account, per date, etc.  If you add yours there, and have a group by the page, that may do what you need.. even if it means nesting any "group by" by having the page number as an outermost group or maybe as an INNER group.  Not sure per lack of specific reporting context.

Now for the expressions.  In the Tablix (grid control of your data source), if you have your expression such as

```
=Sum(CDbl(Fields!Amount.Value))
```

it will do a summation and properly reset itself back to 0 the next time a the group starts (ie: page-based)

Now for GRAND TOTALS.  If you want grand totals for the report, if you tack on the data source to the fields reference, it sums the ENTIRE TABLE, not just the current group...

```
=Sum(CDbl(Fields!Amount.Value, "YourDataSourceAlias" ))
```

This should NOT impact the computations for your other sum() fields in the report, nor require parameters to be passed into the report.